# How to send messages to article writer and @user in your comment when post your comment?

Tags: python, django

I'm using the django.contrib.comment and the form of the comment is like:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post">
```

(I can't find the "comment_form_target" thus I don't know how to use the submit button to send message at the same time when send comment)

And I'm using the django.auth to create user

Comment: Why don't you use signals for this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/signals/